# ON DEVICE TRAINING: Cannot create interpreter: Op builtin_code out of range: 142. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model?

Tags: java, python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Currently using

[these Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptBZP.png)

[from these snapshot repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYPFB.png)

To try and use on device training. As shown in this article by tf
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/on_device_training/overview.

When I try initialising the tflite interpreter I am getting

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Cannot create interpreter: Op builtin_code out of range: 142. Are you using old TFLite binary with newer model?     Registration failed."

I have followed all the instructions provided to create the tflite using tf-nightly '2.7.0-dev20210919' in python. I feel like the dependencies provided in Android might be the issue.

Please Help.

Comment: Yes, I think you should use 

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
}

Comment: yes I have used that dependency with oss.sonatype.org maven, which you can see from the images i've provided above (in a href tags) ..... still doesn't work